# docker ubuntu server LVM disk full?

Tags: 20.04, docker, lvm

First of all I am new to Ubuntu and Linux altogether. Some things that i describe below may not be correct and I might (probably) have done it incorrectly.

I want to know how to set up the volumes and/or Ubuntu the correct way.

I want to make a server out of my old PC, so I bought 2 HDDs for media storage and I'm planning to use my old 125GB SSD for Ubuntu boot, settings and Docker containers.

I installed Ubuntu Server and made a LVM group of the two HDDs to get 1 big storage group. I left the SSD out of this LVM group to keep it apart so I use it just for the OS, boot, swap and docker containers like I said before, however when everything was set up and I used `docker compose` to pull containers, I got the error that my disks were full.

[image: no space left on device error]

so I must have done something wrong with the allocation of partitions. Does someone have advise how I should manage my volumes/partitions/disks?

[image: screenshot of my disk setup]

Comment: Where is `/var/lib/docker` mounted?  If that is on your SSD that's why, you need to specify different storage points for Docker components outside your main system SSD.  Or move all that data from `/var/lib/docker` manually as superuser onto a new LV inside a VG on your LVM disks, and then mount that logical volume at `/var/lib/docker`.  This is a Docker specific config thing,